# Read and block from stdin in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I have our node.js application halt/block, waiting on `stdin` before running the rest of the code? I have:

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

var ECRYPTION_KEY;
rl.question('Provide the global encryption key:', function(encyrptionKey) {
    ECRYPTION_KEY = encyrptionKey;
    rl.close();
});

var https = require('https');

https.createServer({ ... });
console.log("https server running...");
```

Right now, I see `Provide the global encryption key:` and also `https server running..` immediately. I.E. does not block and wait on `stdin` before creating the `https` server.

Comment: Place the `createServer` function inside the callback for the `question()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is being created before the encryption key is received from the `rl` callback.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Ever. Node.js is designed to run without blocking all the time, and waiting for stdin to do something is a misuse.

PS: Actually you can (with fibers) but it is not a good reason to use them.

adeneo's advice is right, just put createServer function inside your callback.